# Getting StaleElementReferenceException after performing checkbox.click()

Tags: webdriver, selenium-webdriver

Getting org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException: Element is no longer attached to the DOM

```
list = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(listLocator));
for (WebElement listItem : list) {

checkbox = listItem.findElement(By.cssSelector(checkboxLocator));
checkbox.click();

String path = checkbox.getCssValue("background-image"));
}
```

After performing   `checkbox.click();` I am not able to call any method on `checkbox` element

corresponding image :
[image]

My Locators are

```
listLocator = ul[class="planList"] > li[class="conditionsTextWrapper"]
checkboxLocator = label[role="button"] > span[class="ui-button-text"]
```

My HTML source before peforming `checkbox.click()` :

```
<ul class="planList">       
 <li class="conditionsTextWrapper" >
   <input name="chkSubOpt" type="checkbox">
   <label class="check ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-button-text-only" for="CAT_5844" aria-pressed="false" role="button">
   <span class="ui-button-text"></span>
   </label>
   <label class="conditionsText">Eat at least 5 fruits and vegetables every day</label>
 </li>
</ul>
```

after performing `checkbox.click()` :

```
<ul class="planList">       
  <li class="conditionsTextWrapper" >
    <input name="chkSubOpt" type="checkbox">
    <label class="check ui-button ui-widget ui-state-default ui-corner-all ui-state-active ui-button-text-only" for="CAT_5844" aria-pressed="true" role="button" aria-disabled="false">
    <label class="conditionsText">Eat at least 5 fruits and vegetables every day</label>
  </li>
 </ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above, the reason of these errors is that the DOM structure has been changed after clicking on the checkbox. The following code works for me.

```
string checkboxXPath = "//input[contains(@id, 'chblRqstState')]";
var allCheckboxes = driver.FindElements(By.XPath(checkboxXPath));

for (int i = 0; i != allCheckboxes.Count; i++)
{
    allCheckboxes[i].Click();
    System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
    allCheckboxes = driver.FindElements(By.XPath(checkboxXPath));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your DOM is changing following the `.click()`, as such the reference `Webdriver` formed to relate to that element (as in the next in your list) is no longer valid. As such you're going to need to rebuild the list within your loop.

```
list = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(listLocator));
for (i=0; list.length(); i++) {
    list = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector(listLocator));
    checkbox = list[i].findElement(By.cssSelector(checkboxLocator));
    checkbox.click();

    String path = checkbox.getCssValue("background-image"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This Happens because your DOM structure has changed since you have referred your check box.

This is a very common Exception which people get.

WorkAround can be to catch the Exception  and try locating and clicking the same element again.

Example

```
    WebElement date = driver.findElement(By.linkText("date"));
 date.click();
                        }
                        catch(org.openqa.selenium.StaleElementReferenceException ex)
                        {
                            log.debug("Exception in finding date");
                            log.debug(e);
                            WebElement date = driver.findElement(By.linkText("date"));
                                                        date.click();
                        }
```

This can solve most of your problems !

Will work for your checkbox problem as well. However i suggest you use @Mark Rowlands solution. His code is cleaner.